# Forbidden (404?) to download yarn artifact using Artifactory and Github

Tags: maven, curl, artifactory, yarnpkg

I have an issue with Jfrog Artifactory and Yarn. I'm not able to download an artifact when I run `mvn clean install ...`

I have added an artifact `yarnpkg-releases` inside my Artifactory. 
It refers to https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/.
This URL on its own returns a 404. I don't know if this is a problem?

My `maven install` tries to download https://my-url/artifactory/yarnpkg-releases/v0.28.4/yarn-v0.28.4.tar.gz and it returns a `404:forbidden`. (Yes not 404 not found or 403 forbidden). 
In my mindset, this URL will resolve to https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v0.28.4/yarn-v0.28.4.tar.gz which returns the right tar.gz.

I have a `.yarn` file in which I configure the URL to my registry and I ignore SSL. What can cause this issue?
Also with a curl (using user:passwd) I got the same error.

I have the same set up for a node artifact. The node artifact points to [this](https://nodejs.org/dist/) URL

When I try `curl -uuser:passwd -O "https://my-url/artifactory/nodejs-dist/v0.1.104/node-v0.1.104.tar.gz"` it works so I don't understand why this is not working for my yarn artifact.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with your URL.

Actual artifactory is available in the below location

https://codeload.github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/tar.gz/v0.28.3/yarn-0.28.3.tar.gz

Comment: That tar.gz is so much bigger than the one on github?

Comment: + The url isn't working: only https://codeload.github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/tar.gz/v0.28.3 but the zip is too big?